# cant call api method using xml in url

Tags: php, api, curl, zoho

I am using zoho api and after editing the user details when i submit a form i create URL and using CURL to call the URL so i can get xml response as "Record updated". Below is the code i m using to send GET request using CURL, I have tried POST request too that didnt worked

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
 var_dump($Rec_Data);
```

It returns "false" but when i use same URL and manually put in browsers address bar and hit anter it works and says "record updated" but with this case i cant check responce and notify user that operation is successfull or something.

Why the same URL isnt working with CURL GET or POST ?? below is my url...if u call below url with browser address bar...it will work but with CURL it doesnt

```
https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/updateRecords?newFormat=1&apikey=*$&ticket=ada47f67f130619aaeab5a40069705c8&xmlData= <Leads> <row no="1"> <FL val="LEADID">418176000000055001</FL> <FL val="SMOWNERID">418176000000047003</FL> <FL val="Lead Owner">418176000000047003</FL> <FL val="Company"> Demo </FL> <FL val="First Name"> Test </FL> <FL val="Last Name"> Lead </FL> <FL val="Designation"> This </FL> <FL val="Email"> email1@yopmail.com </FL> <FL val="Phone"> 242377 </FL> <FL val="Mobile"> 9865986598 </FL> <FL val="Website"> www.google.com </FL> <FL val="Lead Source"> Advertisement </FL> <FL val="Lead Status"> Contact in Future </FL> <FL val="Industry"> Wireless Industry </FL> <FL val="No of Employees">250</FL> <FL val="Annual Revenue"> 19500 </FL> <FL val="Rating"> Active </FL> <FL val="SMCREATORID">418176000000047003</FL><FL val="Created By">418176000000047003</FL> <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">418176000000047003</FL> <FL val="Modified By">Amit</FL> <FL val="Created Time">2012-02-09</FL> <FL val="Modified Time">2012-02-16</FL> <FL val="Email Opt Out"></FL> </row> </Leads> &id=418176000000055001
```

Screenshot of setup 
[image]

Comment: I removed your api key from the question and Akhil's answer. You may want to invalidate it and get a new key from zoho if it grants access to any sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks mike but its demo setup with no sensitive info...i provided the api key so users can see whats happening exactly.

Comment: Is there any other solution :( :( :( ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,urlencode("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/updateRecords?newFormat=1&apikey=*$&ticket=ada47f67f130619aaeab5a40069705c8&xmlData= <Leads> <row no="1"> <FL val="LEADID">418176000000055001</FL> <FL val="SMOWNERID">418176000000047003</FL> <FL val="Lead Owner">418176000000047003</FL> <FL val="Company"> Demo </FL> <FL val="First Name"> Test </FL> <FL val="Last Name"> Lead </FL> <FL val="Designation"> This </FL> <FL val="Email"> email1@yopmail.com </FL> <FL val="Phone"> 242377 </FL> <FL val="Mobile"> 9865986598 </FL> <FL val="Website"> www.google.com </FL> <FL val="Lead Source"> Advertisement </FL> <FL val="Lead Status"> Contact in Future </FL> <FL val="Industry"> Wireless Industry </FL> <FL val="No of Employees">250</FL> <FL val="Annual Revenue"> 19500 </FL> <FL val="Rating"> Active </FL> <FL val="SMCREATORID">418176000000047003</FL><FL val="Created By">418176000000047003</FL> <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">418176000000047003</FL> <FL val="Modified By">Amit</FL> <FL val="Created Time">2012-02-09</FL> <FL val="Modified Time">2012-02-16</FL> <FL val="Email Opt Out"></FL> </row> </Leads> &id=418176000000055001
"));
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);//No caching
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo $buffer;
```

You need to encode ur url before sending ...
In the case of browser, it does this by default.

Comment: Mike thanks for this code....but it still doesnt work :( when i var_dump($buffer) it returns boolean false. Bye the way i m working on localhost...is this the problem ?

Comment: this is api key ="0QL3CBw8Aaptvsj8L0icYKjtJ2x45yNHkQaMGWeIdlI$" in case u need to try urself